# How can I call the displayAd() method?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to execute an AdMob add via a trigger in a webView, but I can't access the method. It keeps asking me to make the method static, but if I do that, I'm not able to access one of my variables.

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
     private WebView mWebView;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_MainActivity);
          MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX");
          mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
          mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX");
          mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
          mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity);
          mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "android");
     }

     public void displayAd() {
          [Ad Code Here]
     }
 }
```

WebAppInterface.java

```
 public class WebAppInterface {
      Context mContext;

      WebAppInterface(Context c) {
          mContext = c;
      }

      @JavascriptInterface
      public void ad() {
          MainActivity.displayAd();
      }
  }
```

This code will not work. How can I change it so that it works?

Comment: Why does this code not work? Please post the error message and highlight any line numbers from the error message in your post.

Comment: @tima Can't even build the project because it says my displayAd() function need to be static. When I change it to static, it loses the reference to the mInterstitialAd element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
public class WebAppInterface {
      MainActivity mainActivity;

      WebAppInterface(MainActivity mainActivity) {
          this.mainActivity= mainActivity;
      }

      @JavascriptInterface
      public void ad() {
          mainActivity.displayAd();
      }
  }
```

and pass the activity reference to interface like

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(MainActivity.this), "android");
```

Comment: Getting "cannot resolve displayAd()" in the WebAppInterface file. That prevents me from building the app.

Comment: @TheAndroidProgrammer Try the updated answer. Change `Activity` to `MainActivity` in Webappinterface file

Comment: That worked... sort of. It will display the log text that I put there for testing, but the ad doesn't actually open. I know that the ad is loaded correctly because I have a listener that ensures the ad is loaded before loading the webView. Currently have `mInterstitialAd.show();` in the displayAd() and mInterstitialAd is a public variable in the MainActivity. Also tried `mainActivity.mInterstitialAd.show()` in the Javascript interface file, but that didn't open the ad either. Any ideas or should I open a new question thread?

Comment: couldn't help without seeing the adcode. 

Off: If my answer helps your sort out the problem in the question, please accept it. And post the adcode so that some one will be able to help.

and, I would advise you to make the ad methods a util class

Comment: Thanks for your help. Was able to find a workaround for my secondary issue, but it would have never worked without your answer. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @TheAndroidProgrammer can you please upvote too... it helps in reputation :-)